# How to embed a text link in an image?

Tags: php, image, text, image-processing, embed

How do I embed text in an image? The embedded text should be hyperlinked to an URL. The use case is like having an image with a link that says 'Click here' which opens a new page.

Answer (score 2):

You have to options to accomplish this:

1. Add your text to the image with your graphics program of choice. (Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) for automated processing) Then create an [image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map) to make parts of the image clickable. If you need some kind of "hot state", then you have to use small images which are absolutely positioned above the original image and show/hide them using Javascript. Depending on your needs it might be easier to make the whole image clickable.
2. Add a normal image and a normal hyperlink. You can use a regular img tag or use set the background image of the container. Then use absolute positioning to move the hyperlink to the desired position on top of the picture. With that solution you don't need Javascript to create a hover effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay away from z-indexes and/or image maps, you could do it the old school way, which is to set the image as a background for a table or div, and then just put text inside the table or div.

Answer (score 1):

Using an image editor add the desired text to image itself and then use the image map to the area where text appears to required URL. For a sample please check my sample at http://shreedhar.kotekar.com/ImageMapSample.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net this [Embed text in Image using ASP.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4648/embed-text-in-image-using-aspnet/) from developer's fusin shows a good example.

**Edit**- From your comments I see you're looking for php: [Adding text to images with PHP](http://www.rafaeldohms.com.br/2008/02/12/adding-text-to-images-in-real-time-with-php/en/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this tool:

http://www.jsclasses.org/package/324-JavaScript-Embed-encoded-text-in-images-using-steganography.html

and here on github:

https://github.com/blauharley/LoremImageCryptonator

With help of this JS-Object you can embed any text you want. It offers two methods (getCryptoImage, getTextFromCryptoImage) that can be used for inserting and extracting any text into and out of an image.

For your use-case you can insert an URL and extract it as soon as the image is clicked.

But first of all you need to create a "Crypto-Image" that a URL has been inserted into before then saves the image. The saved "Crypto-Image" can then be shown on a page.

Hope this helps.